# Get user object from token string in DRF Token In Django using Knox Token

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-knox

I have question related with Django .
I am using Knox Token Authentication to generate tokens for every user when he log in on the page.

Now I want to use that token for every request that will send so I can get the corresponding user for the token. Also I am using custom function example `def dashboard(request)` in Django for every URL route.

I have see on youtube that there are option to get user from token but is not with functions

```
    class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
        permission_classes = [
         permissions.IsAuthenticated,
        ]
        serializer_class = UserSerializer

        def get_object(self):
          return self.request.user
```

So is there a whey to get the corresponding user from a token within a custom function

Comment: this looks fine, you can get the user from the token by sending a get request.

Just add this in the header:

Content-Type: json/application
Authorization: Token (and then insert the actual token here)

Comment: @FlipVermeersch Passing authorization header doesn't populate the request.user for me.

Answer (score 0):

Great, I figured out in hours that knox doesn't come with full token_key stored in database.

Real token we can get is something like:
`a512529e7ffceaa8406ceb616d088b3422ad15811a5eb470e8f4c4896c9aa649`

In database token_key is stored by default `a512529e`. 8 digits.

Filter objects using this:

`knox_object = AuthToken.objects.filter(token_key__startswith=token[:8]).first()`
Then get user object
`knox_object.user.username`

Or you can use this, faster

```
from knox.settings import CONSTANTS
knox_object = AuthToken.objects.filter(token_key=token[:CONSTANTS.TOKEN_KEY_LENGTH]).first()
```

From the knox source codes

```py
class CONSTANTS:
    '''
    Constants cannot be changed at runtime
    '''
    TOKEN_KEY_LENGTH = 8
    DIGEST_LENGTH = 128
    SALT_LENGTH = 16

    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception('''
            Constant values must NEVER be changed at runtime, as they are
            integral to the structure of database tables
            ''')


CONSTANTS = CONSTANTS()
```

You can see `TOKEN_KEY_LENGTH` is of 8 digits.

I wrote a simple function to do that

```py
from knox.models import AuthToken
from knox.settings import CONSTANTS
def get_user_from_token(token):
    objs = AuthToken.objects.filter(token_key=token[:CONSTANTS.TOKEN_KEY_LENGTH])
    if len(objs) == 0:
        return None
    return objs.first().user
```

Life be easier now. :)

### Yes, I improved it and published it.

You may try my fork. If you just simply want to add `@smart_token_user` before any GET/POST/PUT/... methods.

https://github.com/xros/django-rest-knox

Just git clone, and `pip install ./`

I wrote a decorator.

With this,
in our app views.py
we can easily get user object by doing so,`@smart_token_user` will modify the request handler. We can have a `request.user` attr only once the token is valid. And all invalid attempts will be thrown out with HTTP 401 Unauthorized response.
Life can be easier with this decorator.

```py
from knox.models import smart_token_user

class CheckUserEmail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @smart_token_user
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({
            "username": request.user.username,
            "email": request.user.email,
            "password": request.user.password,
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Or use this like original if you want: `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)`

```
class CheckUserEmail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({
            "username": request.user.username,
            "email": request.user.email,
            "password": request.user.password,
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below is a better and more secure way to implement it

```
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication

auth = TokenAuthentication()
user = auth.authenticate_credentials(token)[0]
```